# Cordova / PhoneGap thin loading bar plugin?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli

I was just wondering if anyone knows of any "thin" loading bar plugins for Cordova / PhoneGap. By this, I mean the same thing you see in Safari on an iOS device:

[image: thin loading bar]

The blue line in the image is what I mean.

As the page loads, the blue line extends until the page is fully loaded and it disappears.

Does anything like that exist?

Comment: Did you even find something like this?

Comment: @DirkBoer Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I'm looking for the same stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Try and search the plugin here for what you want:

http://phonegap-plugins.com/

Here is a couple of results you might like:

http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/phonegap-build/statusbarplugin
http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/jonathannaguin/org.apache.cordova.statusbar

Comment: I've searched that site and others prior to posting my question. Unfortunately I couldn't find what I wanted, although that could be because I used the wrong keywords. As for the two that you linked to, they're not what I'm after. Those are statusbar plugins. I'm looking for a loading plugin for the Cordova browser, but thanks for trying!

Comment: Like you want a splash screen? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

Comment: No. If you launch Safari on an iOS device and go to any website, you'll see a line travel across the screen as it loads. This line is a progress line that lets you know when the website has loaded in its entirety.

Comment: @Phil, what do you mean by "Cordova browser"? Are you talking about the InAppBrowser?

Comment: @johnborges I have InAppBrowser installed because I needed it for some functionality (I don't remember which) but by "Cordova Browser" I mean the standard browser that comes with Cordova by default. ie. After I create a new project and build, we're launched into what I'm calling the "Cordova browser"

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Progress Indicator Plugin](https://github.com/pbernasconi/cordova-progressIndicator)This is the most versatile plugin I could find in my search.

This plugin allows you to show a native Progress Indicator on iOS.There are several types of indicators available:

- Simple
- Determinate
- Annular
- Bar
- Success
- Simple Text

Comment: I stumbled onto the Progress Indicator Plugin, and while the Bar type is the closest, it doesn't do what I want unfortunately.

Comment: What johnborges has listed is basically what I want (https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) but I'd prefer it to be native to Cordova / PhoneGap. When you go to the link, you'll notice a blue bar appear at the top. This would be a loading bar in an ideal world.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this with simple JS, which doesn't require a Plugin. Here's one [example](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) using a third party library.

Comment: Thanks @johnborges. If no actual solution exists, this might be what I use. Ideally I would like to have an actual progress bar to be displayed, but I may have to fake it by displaying 25% on link click and when the next page gets displayed, display the remaining 75%.